# Multiple values in callback function from handler. How to bind these values sepretly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

Like handler return these to values..
(ds) as data-set

```
context.Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"]);
context.Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["age"]);
```

then how to bind them or find values secretly.
 for a single value i use

```
function callback(data)
{
     $("#Lbl").html(data);
}
```

But for multiple values?????

Comment: You'll have to add a lot more explanation to your question, and probably show more code. As it is, it's very hard to tell what you're asking, what your goal is, what you're currently doing, etc.

Comment: I send request to server by handler with a single unique ID like '45', Against 45 i have to values, A name, OR age, I save these two values in data-set in handler and then return to page, I already show u returns from handler code and function of page, If i use this for a single value like name, this thing show me correct, but i want to-know to how to bind both values.

Comment: `@QasimRamzan`: Please use the "edit" link under the question to add to it, rather than comments. (And don't worry about the initial downvotes, you're new here, it just takes time to figure out how to do things the StackOverflow way.)

Answer (score 0):

it is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do from your question, but as I understand the question, what I would probably do is turn data into JSON,

you could do this a lot more elegantly by using the built in JSON capabilities of asp.net, but for now change your handler to write the folowing JSON:

```
context.Repsonse.Write("{\"name\":\"" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"]) + "\",";
context.Repsonse.Write("{\"age\":\"" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["age"]) + "\"}";
```

the output should be:

```
  {"name":"name","age":"69"}
```

then you can do something like this on the client side

```
function callback(data)
   {
     var data = $.parseJSON(data);
     $("#name").html(data.name);
     $("#age").html(data.age);
   }
```

edit: added more detail

Comment: I get these two values from handler, Like if i get a single value just name, then  data show me but i just ask how to do this for multiple values.. like for single value i get name by this single line $("#Lbl").html(data);  Name in data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set data to anything you need.
You could build a comma-separated string of values:

```
string res = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"];
res += ";" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["age"];
//and so on...
//remember to check null values and casting
Response.Write(res);
```

Or you could create a JSON string:

```
res = string.format("'name' : '{0}', 'age' : '{1}'", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["age"]);
```

Client side you could for example create such a structure:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

If you choose the comma-separated list, the callback has to handle some string manipulation (.split() method could be handful). If you choose to use JSON see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/